# How to pair a particular class to my bag of words in sci-kit learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, text-classification

I have multiple tf*idf vectors that I would like to pair with an associating class to my training data for use with SVM in sci-kit learn. Is there a sci-kit way to pair a class to a vector of words for use in my training phase?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is exactly what you **DO NOT** want to do when using machine learning. If you will manually associate a certain set of features to an output class then you are not doing anything differently from the statistical methods of the past. The whole point of machine learning is to automate the association of feature sets to output classes. We let the machine determine what patterns in the inputs should be associated with certain classes.

You should build up your dataset, vectorize all your instances in the same way. Then you will feed that matrix to your SVM model and the SVM will determine where to place the boundary such that your classes are differentiated in the hyperspace defined by your features.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear, I am just trying to label my training data and am wondering if there is an easy format for sci-kit learn.